# rails4で変数をviewに渡すと中身が出ない

Tags: ruby-on-rails

users_controller.rb

```
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end
```

views/users/index.html.erb

```
 <p><%= @users %></p>
```

上記のように記述してブラウザで見ると

```
#<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x0055a772872fe8>
```

と表示されています。この内容はどういうことなのでしょうか？

`find all`でusersテーブルのusernameを全て取り出したいのですがどのような記述になりますか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

複数個の`user`モデルが配列のような形で格納されているので、
そのままでは意図した通りに表示することができません。
以下のように記述することで`user`毎に`username`を表示することができます。

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <p><%= user.username %></p>
<% end %>
```